# Half of the days of the year it rains in the morning and when I go to work

Tags: probability

Half of the days of the year it rains in the morning and when I go to work, I take an umbrella with me if he is at home. In the evening, when I return home, I also take an umbrella with me, if I don't forget, which happens in 20% of cases.

It's raining this morning. How likely is it that my umbrella is at home and I will be able to take it?

I'm trying to solve using the full probability formula, but I get more than 1. Perhaps this problem is solved in another way?

H1 = umbrella at home and it`s raining = 0,8 * 0,5 H2 = umbrella at home and it`s not raining = 0,8 * 0,5
H3 = umbrella is not at home and it`s raining = 0,2 * 0,5 H4 = umbrella is not at home and it`s not raining = 0,2 * 0,5
P(A) = 0,82; I thought wrong, now it turned out like this, is this correct?

Comment: You have already made a calculation? You should improve your post by showing us this calculation. Please click "Edit" above.

Answer (score 1):

If we take our umbrella in every day (provided it's there), whether it's raining in the morning or not, and take it home with probability $0.8$ every night, whether we brought it in that day or not, I think it's fair to say there's a $0.8$ probability each morning that we have our umbrella at home, regardless of the weather.